# DataGridView KeyDown Event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, event-handling

Can you figure it out what the problem is with the DataGridView when you are in EditMode?

When I press Enter it will not go to `DatagridView_Keydown` but when I press Enter twice it's working. My goal is to press Enter key once to execute produre.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub DatagridView_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        'Do Procedures
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked `CellEndEdit` event for this purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179517/vb-net-datagridview-modify-currentcell), it has solved my problem with the tab key.

```
Public Class DataGridViewEx
  Inherits DataGridView

  Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Enter then
      Me.ProcessDownKey(keyData)
      Return True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
  End Function
End Class
```

I just modified the `Keys.Tab` to `Keys.Enter`.