# VB.NET Datagridview - Modify currentcell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

This is the first time I ask a question, I'll try to be clear.
I created a datagridview in vb.net which contains 3 columns and 5 rows.
My columns contains job headers. Each row contain information about these jobs : the firstname, lastname, society, phone number, mail.

It looks like :

```
             | J1 | J2 | J3
----------------------------
firstname    | x  | y  | z
lastname     | x1 | y1 | z1
society      | x2 | y2 | z2
phone number | x3 | y3 | z3
mail         | x4 | y4 | z4
```

When i edit the firstname of the job 1 (x), i would like to enter to the lastname's cell of this job (x1) by pressing tab.
Currently, when i press tab, i enter in the firstname's cell of the second job (y).

I tried to change the currentcell after the datagridview.CellEndEdit event. I noticed that the cell (x1) is selected, but the tab key change my edited currentcell to the 'ordinary currentcell' (y).

How can i prevent the tab key to change my edited currentcell ?
Thanks.

Comment: You are going against convention. Why not lay out the rows horizontally? You will not be able to utilize data binding in this manner.

Comment: I know that i don't follow convention, but my manager want this fonctionnality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating your own DataGridView control so you can override the ProcessCmdKey operation:

```
Public Class DataGridViewEx
  Inherits DataGridView

  Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Tab Then
      Me.ProcessDownKey(keyData)
      Return True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
  End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you LarsTech, it work very well ! I replaced Me.ProcessDownKey(keyData) by a programmatically modification of the currentCell.